# Mishneh Torah Tags

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags, tag-synonyms

How should a question regarding a Passage in the Mishneh Torah, (Sefer Shoftim, Mamrim) be tagged?

1. Rambam: Could "also: mishneh-torah" be added to the tag?
2. Mishneh-Torah: As a separate tag - to distinguish questions about the work itself, from the person?
3. Mamrim : And other sections of the Mishneh-Torah
4. Shoftim--book-of : Could "also: neviim-shoftim" be added to that tag? Or shoftim--book-of be an "also" of neviim-shoftim? and "also: shoftim-neviim"?
5. shoftim--mishneh-torah: Could the double hyphen convention apply here?

Comment: I take it this is from [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75850/mamrim-21-who-is-the-rebellious-elder-mentioned-in-the-torah)?

Comment: @DonielF - Yes, but I would like to ask other questions regarding Maimonides, (himself), and the MT.  And - thank you.